# Logitech G27 with Need For Speed: The Run

Tags: controllers, need-for-speed-the-run

I successfully installed Need For Speed: The Run and when configure my controls my Logitech G27 doesn't respond. I choose "wheel" as control (keyboard works fine) but after that any button or action in the G27 doesn't work. I can escape from the "select button" option, so I need to force close my game.

I tried with the Logitech app but neither the "let the game" or "override game setup" options work.

How do I configure it, and does it need special configuration options? My wheel works with other racing games like F1 2011, Dirt 3 and NFS Undercover.

Comment: i am also having this same issue. any help is appreciated

Comment: did it work for you my answer Don? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What really happens is that NFS The Run doesnt work with another joystick connected and Logitech G27. I unplug all my joystick and then just connect the logitech g27 and it works.